# How can i skip same post from taxonomy term?

Tags: custom-post-types, wp-query, custom-taxonomy

I'm trying to retrieve the posts of specific taxonomy categories. I have two taxonomy categories.

1. Category One
2. Category Two

In these two have some different and same posts. So when i retrieve the data through `terms id` then query return some post two times, because these posts are link from above two categories.

```
$ourwork_cat_ids = array(3,4);// Category Term ID
$args_OW = array();
foreach($ourwork_cat_ids as $wIds){
    $args_OW[] = array(
    'post_type' => 'portfolio',
    'tax_query' => array(
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'portfolio_category',
            'field' => 'id',
            'terms' => $wIds
         )
      )
    );
}//end foreach
foreach($args_OW as $OW){
    $portfolioQuery = new WP_Query($OW);
    if( $portfolioQuery->have_posts() ){ 
            while( $portfolioQuery->have_posts() ){ $portfolioQuery->the_post(); 
                echo the_title().'<br />';
            }
    }

}// end foreach

 Out Put
post one 
post two 
post two
post three
```

So is there possible that i can skip double post ? I will appreciate if someone guide me for that. Thanks.

Comment: You're misusing `WP_Query`. Query inside `foreach` loop? **Very.. bad.. idea**. You can easily make just one query which would also eliminate double posts problem. [Take a look at the codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Category_Parameters).

Comment: @N00b do you know i'm using custom taxonomy and are you sure this method will work on custom taxonomy category ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should never use `WP_Query` inside that kind of loop *(there might be few exceptions but not in your case)* because you can do most things with one query. This [codex link](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query) has everything related to `WP_Query` with explanations and very simple examples.

If taxonomies were a list of groceries and a trip to shop would be a query I doubt you would go to shop for each item separately. No, you will go once and buy them all.

---

Take a look at these examples and let me know if you're having any problems.

```
//If you're using actual categories
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'portfolio',
    'cat' => '2, 4, 5, 77, 1031' // Category IDs
);

//If you're using single custom taxonomy
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'portfolio',
    'tax_query' => array(
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'portfolio_tax',
            'field'    => 'term_id',
            'terms'    => array( 2, 4, 5, 77, 1031 ) // Term IDs
        )
    )
);

//If you're using multiple custom taxonomies
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'portfolio',
    'tax_query' => array(
        'relation' => 'AND',  // Relation can be 'AND' or 'OR'
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'portfolio_tax',
            'field'    => 'term_id',
            'terms'    => array( 2, 4, 5, 77, 1031 ) // Term IDs
        ),
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'second_tax',
            'field'    => 'term_id',
            'terms'    => array( 1, 3, 6, 81, 1251 ) // Term IDs
        )
    )
);


//Query itself with output
$query_results = new WP_Query( $args );

while( $query_results->have_posts() ) { 

    $query_results->the_post(); 
    echo the_title() . '<br />';
}
```

Comment: You give me great, perfect and short coded answer, I appreciate you and your knowledge. Its working fine.

Answer (score 0):

You are doing it wrong. You don't need to use a `foreach` loop here. `tax_query` parameter `terms` can be `int` or `string` or `array`.

You can make your code more simple like this:

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'portfolio',
    'tax_query' => array(
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'portfolio_category',
            'field' => 'id',
            'terms' => array(3,4);// Category Term ID
         )
      )
    );
```

To skip double post, we can use `posts_distinct` filter. We need to put it before our `WP_Query`.

```
function search_distinct() {
    return "DISTINCT";
}
add_filter('posts_distinct', 'search_distinct');
```

Now, here is our `WP_Query`:

```
$portfolioQuery = new WP_Query($args);
if( $portfolioQuery->have_posts() ){ 
        while( $portfolioQuery->have_posts() ){ $portfolioQuery->the_post(); 
            echo the_title().'<br />';
        }
}
wp_reset_postdata();
```

We will need to remove the filter.

```
remove_filter('posts_distinct', 'search_distinct');
```

Comment: `WP_Query` does not return duplicate posts by default, even when you pass duplicate ID's to it.

Comment: @PieterGoosen Okay I wasn't aware of that. Then what is the purpose of `posts_distinct` filter?